# Load data from database in thumbnail grid with expanding preview without using anchor tag data-description attribute

Tags: jquery, html, grid, responsive-design

I want to implement thumbnail grid with expanding preview but i need to call data from data base.

I do not want to use below code :

```
<a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro"  >
 <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02" />
</a>
```

because it contents **data-largesrc**, **data-description** etc..

i want below format :

```
<div class="og-expander">
        <div class="og-expander-inner">
            <span class="og-close"></span>
            <div class="og-fullimg">
                <div class="og-loading"></div>
                <img src="images/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="og-details">
                <h3>Veggies sunt bona vobis</h3>
                <p>Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.</p>
                <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/">Visit website</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Reference Link :

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/